# AEM Query builder search where property 'does not' exist

Tags: aem, query-builder, jcr

I need o do a search in AEM query builder and tying to only fetch the tags that have not been moved to a new location.

The only property added to the **old** tags is the "`cq:movedTo`" which has the path to the new location.

But when I try to search the tags which **don't** have this property, I dont get any results:

```
property=cq:movedTo
property.operation=no
```

Am I missing something here ? The search is done by a 3rd party and cannot process the list of tags it receive. So I need to fetch ONLY the correct list with this query.

Answer (score 10):

property.operation can take one of the following values while using the property predicate evaluator.

1. `equals` for an exact match.
2. `unequals`
3. `like` partial matching
4. `not` for no match
5. `exists` for existence match

In your case to search for all nodes containing the property `cq:movedTo` you can use

```
property=cq:movedTo
property.operation=exists
```

If you want all nodes that don't have the property then specify the value as false.

```
property=cq:movedTo
property.operation=exists
property.value=false
```

More information on possible values for the property predicate evaluator can be found [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.html).

Answer (score 0):

You specify path and type then you add the following:

```
    property=cq:movedTo
    property.operation=not
    p.limit=-1
```

The last line (p.limit=-1) will let you see all the results, w/o it you will be seeing only the first ten hits.